# How to get all element in xml file using with CURL and DOM put into the array?

Tags: php, arrays, xml, curl, dom

I need some help with code. I want to get all element in xml file using with CURL and DOM into the array.

Can you help me with this?

My PHP with CURL code shown in below:

```
<?php

$key = 'ad12rqwagst3ewtgsdhdsdsfsdgsd';

$url = 'http://api.11street.my/rest/cateservice/category';

$request_body = 'xml data';

$headers = array(
    'openapikey: ' . $key,
    'Accept-Charset: utf-8',
    'Content-Type: application/xml'
);

$curl = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
$arrXml = array();
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($result);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('dispEngNm') as $item) {
    $arrXml[] = $dom->saveXML($item) . "<br>" . "<hr>";
} 

print_r($arrXml);

?>
```

The example code of xml file show in below, these are three items I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
</ns2:categorys>
<ns2:category>
    <depth>1</depth>
    <dispEngNm>Women Clothing</dispEngNm>
    <dispNm>Women Clothing</dispNm>
    <dispNo>2021</dispNo>
    <parentDispNo>0</parentDispNo>
</ns2:category>
<ns2:category>
    <depth>2</depth>
    <dispEngNm>Women Tops</dispEngNm>
    <dispNm>Women Tops</dispNm>
    <dispNo>2051</dispNo>
    <parentDispNo>2021</parentDispNo>
</ns2:category>
<ns2:category>
    <depth>3</depth>
    <dispEngNm>Tanks &amp; Camisoles</dispEngNm>
    <dispNm>Tanks &amp; Camisoles</dispNm>
    <dispNo>2209</dispNo>
    <parentDispNo>2051</parentDispNo>
</ns2:category>
</ns2:categorys>
```

The output is shown me below:

```
Array ( [0] => Women Clothing
[1] => Women Tops
[2] => Tanks & Camisoles
[3] => T-shirts
```

I just can get element "dispEngNm" into the array. Anyone know how can get other element "dispNm","dispNo", "parentDispNo" together with "dispEngNm" into the array?

Thanks for your helping! Wish you have a nice day!

Comment: It seems the xml that you have posted is invalid.  Or so `simplexml_load_string()` tells me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the code you have so far and using the ability of SimpleXML to iterate through the child elements easily, the code below first looks for the `<category>` elements (`getElementsByTagName()` doesn't worry about namespaces), then import it into SimpleXML so that you can just `foreach()` over the child elements and add them into a work array (using the tag name as the key).  This just copies all of the child data into an associative array...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($result);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('category') as $item) {
    $sxml = simplexml_import_dom($item);
    $newData = [];
    foreach ( $sxml as $tag => $value ) {
        $newData[$tag] = (string)$value;
    }
    $arrXml[] = $newData;
}

print_r($arrXml);
```

gives...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [depth] => 1
            [dispEngNm] => Women Clothing
            [dispNm] => Women Clothing
            [dispNo] => 2021
            [parentDispNo] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [depth] => 2
            [dispEngNm] => Women Tops
            [dispNm] => Women Tops
            [dispNo] => 2051
            [parentDispNo] => 2021
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [depth] => 3
            [dispEngNm] => Tanks & Camisoles
            [dispNm] => Tanks & Camisoles
            [dispNo] => 2209
            [parentDispNo] => 2051
        )

)
```

Comment: DOMDocument also allows you to iterate through children via the `childNodes` property of DOMNode, [there is no need to involve simpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55740566/1067003)

Answer (score 0):

Just change this code:

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('dispEngNm') as $item) {
    $arrXml[] = $dom->saveXML($item) . "<br>" . "<hr>";
}
```

by this code:

```
$allTags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('ns2:category');
for ($i =0; $i < $allTags.length; $i++) {
    $childLen = $allTags[i].childNodes.length;
    $innerChilds = $allTags[i].firstChild;
    for ($j = 0; $j < $childLen; $j++) {
        $arrXml[] = $dom->saveXML($innerChilds.innerHTML) . "<br>" . "<hr>"; 
        $innerChilds = $innerChilds.nextSibling;
    }
}
```

In the above code, I am just loading all the child nodes of `ns2:category` which may works.

Note: I have not tested the code. You may test this and make changes if required.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I try using your code but the error come ous "Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string in /home/isqestore/public_html/middleware/api_11street/getname.php on line 31"

Comment: What do you have on line no 31?

Comment: line 31- foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('dispEngNm') as $item) {

Comment: @AwesomeBoy In my provided solution I don't use the line which you are mentioned on line no 31

Comment: Ok, understood. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

maybe you're looking for the `childNodes` property?

```
$arrXml = array();
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName("category") as $cat){
    $curr=array();
    foreach($cat->childNodes as $child){
            $curr[$child->nodeName]=$dom->saveXML($child);
    }
    $arrXml[]=$curr;
}
unset($cat,$curr,$child);
print_r($arrXml);
```

working example:

```
<?php

$xml=<<<'XML'
<ns2:category>
    <depth>1</depth>
    <dispEngNm>Women Clothing</dispEngNm>
    <dispNm>Women Clothing</dispNm>
    <dispNo>2021</dispNo>
    <parentDispNo>0</parentDispNo>
</ns2:category>
<ns2:category>
    <depth>2</depth>
    <dispEngNm>Women Tops</dispEngNm>
    <dispNm>Women Tops</dispNm>
    <dispNo>2051</dispNo>
    <parentDispNo>2021</parentDispNo>
</ns2:category>
<ns2:category>
    <depth>3</depth>
    <dispEngNm>Tanks &amp; Camisoles</dispEngNm>
    <dispNm>Tanks &amp; Camisoles</dispNm>
    <dispNo>2209</dispNo>
    <parentDispNo>2051</parentDispNo>
</ns2:category>
XML;
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($xml);
$arrXml = array();
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName("category") as $cat){
    $curr=array();
    foreach($cat->childNodes as $child){
            $curr[$child->nodeName]=$dom->saveXML($child);
    }
    $arrXml[]=$curr;
}
unset($cat,$curr,$child);
print_r($arrXml);
```

- btw if you don't actually want the xml but just the text content, then change

```
$curr[$child->nodeName]=$dom->saveXML($child);
```

with

```
$curr[$child->nodeName]=$child->textContent;
```

instead, and it will contain the text of the child, rather than the xml

btw here is what the sample code above with the textContent patch outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [depth] => 1
            [dispengnm] => Women Clothing
            [dispnm] => Women Clothing
            [dispno] => 2021
            [parentdispno] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [depth] => 2
            [dispengnm] => Women Tops
            [dispnm] => Women Tops
            [dispno] => 2051
            [parentdispno] => 2021
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [depth] => 3
            [dispengnm] => Tanks & Camisoles
            [dispnm] => Tanks & Camisoles
            [dispno] => 2209
            [parentdispno] => 2051
        )

)
```

Comment: @mickmackusa you're right, i had to do `getElementsByTagName("category")` instead of `getElementsByTagName("ns2:category")`, not sure why. anyway, fixed and added a working example

Comment: Why do you use `loadHTML()`?  You would need to add the root node (with namespace) to load it properly, but also noticed if you do this and use `loadXML()` you end up with extra data in the output.

Comment: @NigelRen because if i used loadXML then i would have to add the xml header, something like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`, and that header was absent in the test data provided when i wrote the code - that header has since been actually added to the test data, but too late. ... but what is this `extra data in the output` you're talking about?

Comment: You don't need an xml declaration, although you would need to add a root node (something like `<ns2:categories xmlns:ns2="http://some.url">`) and the closing equivalent.  If you then changed it to `loadXML()` your first element would be `[#text] => `.  Try it for yourself.  Although you can fix this by adding `$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;` before the load.

Comment: @NigelRen well loadHTML() needs neither an xml declaration nor does it need a root node, which is why i used it instead of loadXML()

Answer (score 0):

Generic conversion into an array are possible, but most of the time you just loose features and data. DOM includes Xpath, so most of the time it makes more sense to read the data directly into a SPECIFIC array/object structure. In you case you have a list of records with parent-child relations.

Your XML includes a namespace prefix `ns2` but the definition for it is missing. Look for an attribute `xmlns:ns2` - its value is the actual namespace.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:categorys xmlns:ns2="urn:ns2">
<ns2:category>
    <depth>1</depth>
    <dispEngNm>Women Clothing</dispEngNm>
    <dispNm>Women Clothing</dispNm>
    <dispNo>2021</dispNo>
    <parentDispNo>0</parentDispNo>
</ns2:category>
<ns2:category>
    <depth>2</depth>
    <dispEngNm>Women Tops</dispEngNm>
    <dispNm>Women Tops</dispNm>
    <dispNo>2051</dispNo>
    <parentDispNo>2021</parentDispNo>
</ns2:category>
<ns2:category>
    <depth>3</depth>
    <dispEngNm>Tanks &amp; Camisoles</dispEngNm>
    <dispNm>Tanks &amp; Camisoles</dispNm>
    <dispNo>2209</dispNo>
    <parentDispNo>2051</parentDispNo>
</ns2:category>
</ns2:categorys>
XML;

// this needs to be the value of the xmlns:ns2 attribute
$ns_categories = 'urn:ns2';

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
// register an prefix for the namespace
$xpath->registerNamespace('c', $ns_categories);

$categories = [];
$tree = [];
// iterate the categories
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//c:categorys/c:category') as $category) {
    // casting a node list in Xpath will return the content of the first node
    $id = (int)$xpath->evaluate('number(dispNo)', $category);
    $parentId = (int)$xpath->evaluate('number(parentDispNo)', $category);
    // store category data 
    $categories[$id] = [
        'id' => $id,
        'parent_id' => $parentId,
        'depth' => (int)$xpath->evaluate('number(depth)', $category),
        'caption' => $xpath->evaluate('string(dispNm)', $category),
        'caption_english' => $xpath->evaluate('string(dispEngNm)', $category),
    ];
    // store child ids for each parent 
    if (!isset($tree[$parentId])) {
      $tree[$parentId] = [];
    }
    $tree[$parentId][] = $id; 
}

var_dump($categories, $tree);
```

The main differences that if you read the result of a generic conversion the array keys can have different names or can be missing. The result structure depends directly on the input. If you read the data into a specific structure (like my example) you know which array keys are there.